# Finding all complex solutions to $iz = \overline{z}(4-z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find all complex solutions to $iz = \overline{z}(4-z)$

So first, we have $z = re^{i \theta}$ and $\overline{z} = re^{- i \theta}$. So

$$i\cdot re^{i \theta} = re^{- i \theta} (4 - r e^{i \theta})$$

$$i\cdot re^{i \theta} =4re^{-i \theta} - r^2 e^{2i \theta}$$

But beyond this point, I become stuck. I'm not certain that the $i$ on the LHS should be sitting there next to the $re^{i \theta}$. Can anyone give me guidance on how to solve for $r$ and $\theta$? Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: You multiplied out the right side incorrectly, it should be $\ldots - r^2$ instead.

Comment: @Ramanujan I have $r^2$ in the last line of the RHS

Comment: But the $e^{2i\theta}$ shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use complex conjugation instead of taking real and imaginary parts.

Start with the original equation and it's conjugate

$iz=\overline z (4-z)$

$-i\overline z=z(4-\overline z)$

The first equation may be solved for $\overline z$ and the resulting expression substituted into the second, giving an equation containing only $z$:

$\overline z = \dfrac{iz}{4-z}$

$\dfrac{z}{4-z}=z(4-\dfrac{iz}{4-z})$

One solution is

$z=0$.

An equation for other solutions is obtained by dividing out $z$ and clearing fractions:

$1=4(4-z)-iz$

$z=\dfrac{15}{4+i}=\dfrac{60}{17}-\dfrac{15}{17}i.$

This matches other answers and the solution set

$\{0, \dfrac{60}{17}-\dfrac{15}{17}i\}$

checks with the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that $0$ is a solution. Suppose now that $z\ne0$. Then\begin{align}iz=\overline z(4-z)&\implies|iz|=\left|\overline z(4-z)\right|\\&\iff|z-4|=1.\end{align}So, if there is a solution other that $0$, it will have to be of the form $z=4+w$, for some $w\in\Bbb C$ with $|w|=1$. And then\begin{align}iz=\overline z(4-z)&\iff 4i+iw=-\left(4+\overline w\right)w=-4w-1\\&\iff w=-\frac8{17}-\frac{15i}{17}.\end{align}Since $\left|-\frac8{17}-\frac{15i}{17}\right|=1$ we can take $w=-\frac8{17}-\frac{15i}{17}$. Therefore, if there is another solution, it has to be$$4-\frac8{17}-\frac{15i}{17}=\frac{60}{17}-\frac{15i}{17}.$$And it is easy to check that it is indeed a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. However I am slightly confused. How did you obtain $e^{i \theta} = - \frac{8}{17} - \frac{15}{17}i$?

Comment: I have edited my answer. But note that\begin{align}4i+iw=-4w-1&\iff w(4+i)=-1-4i\\&\iff w=\frac{1-4i}{4+i}=-\frac8{17}-\frac{15i}{17}.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be rewritten as $iz = 4\bar{z} - |z|^2$.
Writing $z = a + bi$, this becomes
$$ia - b = 4(a - ib) - a^2 - b^2$$
Splitting into real and imaginary parts, you get two equations
$$-b = 4a - a^2 - b^2$$
$$a = -4b$$
So now you have to just find the solutions to the above system. It's the intersection of a line through the origin with a circle, so you will get two solutions.